# mysql | Duplicate Entry for PK - Non PK value change fixed issue - Why?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, composite-primary-key

### Issue

When I try to import an CSV file, I recieve the `Duplicate entry 'x-x-xx-x-x-x' for key 'PRIMARY'`-errors for the PK.

The PK itself are two concated **varchar**s. And as much I can tell, are concated never a duplicate.

*My first idea was, that maybe the length of the **varchar** wouldn't be enough for both keys and a composite-key could just use the length of one key. So I altered both two a value which should fit even such a character length (10 to 16) and… no successed. Same error.*

**But then** it became strange:

I've edited (just for fun) all `value`-values into `1.0`.
And suddenly, the whole import worked without any warning.

**But… how? And more important why?**

How can the value causing an `Duplicate entry '1-b-21-1-b-20' for key 'PRIMARY'` error, when they're even not a part of the (composite) PK?

### Files

Original files have over 5000.

I reduced the two example CSV files to the only issuing ones:

[Gist | CSV - 2 Files | 1 working | 1 issued](https://gist.github.com/inovek/c70becb24a82fc432372285c17aea5a1)

### Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `route_neighbours` (
  `start` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `end` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `distance` decimal(10,1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`start`,`end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

### Errors:

```sql
2002:2: Duplicate entry '1-j-23-1-i-23' for key 'PRIMARY'
2003:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-17-1-b-18' for key 'PRIMARY'
2004:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-18-1-b-19' for key 'PRIMARY'
2005:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-19-1-b-20' for key 'PRIMARY'
2006:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-20-1-b-21' for key 'PRIMARY'
2007:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-21-1-b-22' for key 'PRIMARY'
2008:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-22-1-b-23' for key 'PRIMARY'
2009:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-23-1-b-24' for key 'PRIMARY'
2010:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-24-1-b-23' for key 'PRIMARY'
2011:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-23-1-b-22' for key 'PRIMARY'
2012:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-22-1-b-21' for key 'PRIMARY'
2013:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-21-1-b-20' for key 'PRIMARY'
2014:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-20-1-b-19' for key 'PRIMARY'
2015:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-19-1-b-18' for key 'PRIMARY'
2016:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-18-1-b-17' for key 'PRIMARY'
2017:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-17-1-b-16' for key 'PRIMARY'
2018:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-16-1-b-15' for key 'PRIMARY'
2019:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-15-1-b-14' for key 'PRIMARY'
2020:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-14-1-b-13' for key 'PRIMARY'
2021:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-13-1-b-12' for key 'PRIMARY'
2022:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-12-1-b-11' for key 'PRIMARY'
2023:2: Duplicate entry '1-b-11-1-b-10' for key 'PRIMARY'
... and much  more lines of these error ...
```

Comment: How are you importing? If using load data infile please add load statement to question.

Comment: Is the published table definition correct - it shouldn't even syntax?(startnode and endnode do not exist)

Comment: There are duplicates in your data 'Duplicate entry '1-j-23-1-i-23' for key 'PRIMARY' the value 1-j-23-1-i-23 shows the concatenated (and separated by - ) start and end values - and I have checked they are duplicates in your data.

Comment: @P.Salmon Oh you're right, I removed the node-phrase to make it easier to read. Forgot to remove it from the above example. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the primary key defined in the `CREATE TABLE` query can't exist, for the defined fields don't exist.

Also, the CSV indeed has duplicate records, for example: `1-bl-1;1-x-1;10.0`.

Using bash, you can count the unique lines versus all the lines:

```
# All lines: 1568
cat Issued.csv | wc -l

# Unique lines: 1531
cat Issued.csv | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

So it's not the value causing any errors, it's the duplicate keys.

Comment: Thank you and ouch, your terminal commands helped me alot to solve the issue and see where my old comfy way failed really hard.